# Carrying Liquor from Heathrow to Bangalore via Abu Dhabi

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, alcohol, abu-dhabi

I am travelling to Bangalore via Abu Dhabi from London. 
Can i get liquor from duty free shop in Heathrow? Will it be confiscated in Abu Dhabi?

Comment: I found thru personal travel in UAE several years ago that many persons like to drink and are fond of your passports too. Keep a close eye on your bottles in transit and passport always in locked safe box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no prohibition on transiting through the UAE with alcohol; non-Muslim visitors can even bring in 4 liters past customs. It's even sold on board your Etihad flight and in the duty free in Abu Dhabi. You will have no problem, provided that the duty free places your purchase in one of the plastic security bags (otherwise you would be limited to carrying 100mL through security).

Comment: I traveled recently and there was no problem at all. I got the liquor in a tamper proof bag.

Answer (score 1):

According to IATA https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/AE-United-Arab-Emirates-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm#Import%20regulations, free import of up to 4 liters of any kind of alcohol is permitted by Abu Dhabi for non-muslim passengers only.

As stated by @Michael Hampton, the bottle(s) will need to be carried in the duty free bag in which they are sealed at the point of purchase.

Comment: This is relevant if importing.  But the OP is in transit and hence not importing anything into the UAE and this is therefore not relevant.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Noted, however the OP does not specifically state that they will be transiting airside.

Comment: The question is tagged with "Transit", so unless otherwise stated this should be assumed.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I disagree. One should never assume anything. Tags can be chosen incorrectly or omitted; ‘transit’ can mean different things to different people (airside, landside, layover?).

Comment: Well you have assumed that they are transferring landside and hence are importing into the UAE.  So you have also made an assumption!  Most people transit airside and on a single ticket (although not relevant here).

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith Does it make any difference here? If the OP can legally import 4L, surely they can take 4L through transit as well.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Yes, in most cases the regulations for transit and import are totally different.